# Blazor WASM doesn't hit breakpoint

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor WASM Project with version 5 assemblies and tried to activate debugging according to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.1

For that I made sure I updated all the assembly references and adjusted the launchsettings. The latter looks like that now:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:62310",
      "sslPort": 44325
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ApplySupportTool.Client": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also these are my references in the WASM Project:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20210.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation" Version="3.2.0-preview2.20160.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Runtime" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.8" />
```

For testing I copied over the "Counter" page from the default project. But when I hit F5 to debug the breaking point in the `IncrementCount` method doesn't turn red.
I tested in a new created default project and there it works, so I pressume Visual Studio Preview, Edge and .net core has the correct version.

What I noticed is this warning in the dev console which only appears in my existing project, but not in the new created default project:

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ndcileolkflehcjpmjnfbnaibdcgglog/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Is there something other I have to add or adjust for this to work? In the article above I couldn't find anything as far as I can see.

Comment: Same here, I had it working before the last update though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267303/blazor-client-side-debugging have you seen this post? possible duplicate

Answer (score 17):

This is a known issue in Blazor projects at this time. The debugger launches slower/quicker than the project assembly and doesn't have time to "see" the assembly. Here is my fix until they solve this. I add a delay in Program.cs so that when the project launches in debug mode, it gives the debugger time to attach properly. I used 5000 ms but you may have to increase this value if your machine is slower than mine.

```
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task DebugDelayAsync()
        {
#if DEBUG
            await Task.Delay(5000);
#endif
        }

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await DebugDelayAsync();

            (...)
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried many solutions even one from official aspnetcore repo but this worked like a charm ... lol

Comment: Over a year later, this is still an issue in VS2019 and this is still the only solution I found that actually worked.

Comment: I had the exact same issue with .NET 5 (in 2022). I had to add Delay() function to the Program.cs and then it worked as expected. Then I tried without it (Delay(5000 in Program.cs)) and still worked.

Answer (score 4):

This may help someone. In my case I deleted the hidden .vs folder for the solution and break points worked again. In addition this fixed an issue where Chrome Debugging would not work any longer.

Comment: This worked for me as well when all other suggestions did not (launch settings, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me a few days ago.

The steps I took were as follows:

- **Edit the debug profile**. In my case, I edited the port and removed the https protocol option.
- **Compile** and check that the debugging points were working again.
- **Edit the debug profile to return to the initial configuration**. I didn’t undo the changes, I edited them by hand again

Answer (score 0):

if earlier methods didn't work also try:

1. implement the DebugDelay from the top answer.
2. with notepad, open [your project]\Client\Properties\launchSettings.json
3. Under iisSettings.. "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50454", copy the local host .eg. http://localhost:50454
4. In Visual Studio IDE, Debug, [my app].server.debug* properties / webserver settings / App URL. Paste in your clipboard.

don't ask me why it worked but it did, the annoying 'Unbound breakpoint will not be hit' was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these bugs have been fixed since .NET 6 and the update to the SDK in 6.0.202.

*The workaround of using a timer is no longer needed* - so don't go down that path.

But there are still various bugs and difficulties based on environment. If you are willing to use Edge (it's good), then see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037574) for working config.

Comment: using VS 2022, debugging works with NET 7, but not with NET 6 in my case, although the breakpoint is solid and gets a yellow warning sign when debugging has started, just like in NET 7. Difference is, that breakpoint is hit in NET 7 project.

Answer (score -1):

If none of the above works, not having the SSL certificate for localhost in the trusted root store will also prevent you from debugging client side C#. So if you still have an "unsecured connection" try adding the cert first.