# Blazor WebAssembly Breakpoints not working

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to debug a Blazor web assembly app with breakpoints.

If I add a breakpoint within Visual Studio I get this message on my breakpoint.

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit no symbols where loaded for
> this document.

I updated visual studio.

I made sure the inspectUri was added to both the client and server setting.json.

I unchecked enable diagnostic tool while debugging in settings.

I tried to run as administrator.
I also tried the answer here: [How do I remedy "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been)

Any help will be appreciated

Regards,

Comment: I'm also having this same problem. I guess I hadn't tried it until now. I've got a foreach loop wrapped around some HTML and I go and add a variable into it with a breakpoint set. The breakpoint gives me this same message.

Comment: It works on my end. Try to use Edge Browser and wait for a couple of seconds. If not try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63499076/12963806 Thanks. Hope this helps you. I'm using visual studio IDE

Answer (score 0):

At the begining you should know WASM debuging works on Chromium browsers like Edge and Chrome. Then make this changes.

Open `launchSetting.json` file, in `IIS Express` profile and add this code after `"launchBrowser": true,`:

```
"inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
```

Repeat it for other profiles, for example `TestBlazor.WASM`.

This peace of code:

- Enables the IDE to detect that the app is a Blazor WebAssembly app.
- Instructs the script debugging infrastructure to connect to the
  browser through Blazor's debugging proxy.

Those changes works well but in some cases that failed, add this `"nativeDebugging": true` to all profiles.

If your App hosts on another base app than `/`, change the properties like this:

```
"iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:{INSECURE PORT}/{APP BASE PATH}/",
    "sslPort": {SECURE PORT}
}
```

And for each profiles:

```
"inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/{APP BASE PATH}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
```

Comment: Hey @Shadman. My app launches on another base path than `/` and I have tried to use your advice but didn't succeed. Maybe you have some repository on GitHub with a configuration json file?