# Blazor WebAssembly broswer debugging with VS Code rarely hits (some) breakpoints

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, debugging, blazor-webassembly

I have been working on this issue past several months. I'm running windows 10 with VS Code and newest version of dotnet 6.

I have a blazor wasm **standalone** project that I am trying to debug. When I run debug from VS Code it only hits breakpoints in Program.cs and very rarely (mysteriously) inside .razor files where I am actually trying to hit them.

Also more mysteriousness came when I created new blank blazor wasm project and on it breakpoints hit normally.

To check my sanity I got an ubuntu machine copied the blazor project to it and all breakpoints were hitting like it should.

I'v tried:

- removing bin and obj and then rebuilding
- disabling browser cache
- awaiting in program.cs (refering to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469337/blazor-wasm-doesnt-hit-breakpoint))
- explicitly setting browsers in launch.json (tried both edge and chrome)
- other things

## Environment info

**VS Code info:**

```
Version: 1.86.2 (user setup)
Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
Date: 2024-02-13T19:40:56.878Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26908389
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

**dotnet --info:**

```
.NET SDK:
Version:           8.0.101
Commit:            6eceda187b
Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.69afb982

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.19042
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win-x64
Base Path:   C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\8.0.101\\

.NET workloads installed:
Workload version: 8.0.100-manifests.69afb982
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
Version:      8.0.1
Architecture: x64
Commit:       bf5e279d92

.NET SDKs installed:
6.0.418 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\]
8.0.101 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.26 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.1 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.26 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.NETCore.App\]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.1 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.NETCore.App\]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.26 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.1 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\]

Other architectures found:
None

Environment variables:
Not set

global.json file:
Not found
```

## Project info:

**Properties/launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61808",
      "sslPort": 44366
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5244",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7050;http://localhost:5111",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.FluentValidation" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="11.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.26" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="6.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\NotRunnableProjects\SM.ServiceLayer.BlazorSPA\SM.ServiceLayer.BlazorSPA.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\NotRunnableProjects\SM.Shared\SM.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```