# Blazor Client Debug Breakpoint shows Message not found error

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im'trying to debug a Blazor WebAssembly app using VisualStudio 2022. Everytime I launch the app with a breakpoint activated, it shows like this:

[image]

I have checked that the inspectUri attribute is setted in launchSettings.json. There is no error in the output window of VS.

Any idea what may be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: The debugger is not able to hit the breakpoint. Have confirmed that you are launching in debug mode? Did you build with the latest changes?

Comment: Some resources that may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/56267303/6865932 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/61469337/6865932

Comment: Yes, app is in debug mode, builded with all changes.

Comment: Also, I have tried all things commented in those posts and it is still not working