# Blazor client side debugger not observing values

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm unable to debug Blazor client side app.

I went throug MS docs and I can connect to the Chrome debugger.
When the breakpoint is hit the app stops as expected but I cannot observe any value. All I get is a local scope with `this` variable that is undefined. 
Here is a screenshot of what I'm describing. I'm trying to debug Counter component and would like to see the `currentCount` value

The only thing I don't understand from the docs is 
*Pass the --configuration Debug option to the dotnet run command*
Should I do that and how when using Visual Studio?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know client side debugging is not yet supported. See
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246560/blazor-client-side-debugging-fails)

Other option is to switch over to server side blazor where you can use debugging, once done you can switch back.

Or use `Console.Writeline(currentCount);`. The value will appear in the browser console as WASM: value of currentcount.